# How to decode/decompress values from memcached-backed Rails cache (Dalli gem) in Node.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, caching, zlib

I have a Rails application that is caching data in memcached via the Dalli gem (https://github.com/mperham/dalli).

I would like to read the contents of this cache from Node.js. I am using the mc module to interface with memcached in Node.js.

The problem I'm running into is with encoding and compression. Dalli uses `Zlib::Deflate.deflate(data)` (https://github.com/mperham/dalli/blob/master/lib/dalli/compressor.rb). When I attempt to inflate from Node.js I get an error when trying to inflate with the zlib module:

```
{ [Error: incorrect header check] errno: -3, code: 'Z_DATA_ERROR' }
```

Here is relevant Ruby/Rails code:

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store, memcached_server, {compress: true}
```

And the relevant Node.js code:

```
client = new Memcached.Client(MEMCACHED_HOSTNAME, Memcached.Adapter.raw);


client.get(key, function (err, response) {
  var data = response[key];

  zlib.inflate(data.buffer, function (err, buf) {
    console.log(err, buf);
  });
});
```

The buffer the comes back from memcached's string value looks like this:

`'\u0004\b[\u0015i\u0006i\u0007i\bi\ti\ni\u000bi\fi\ri\u000ei\u000fi\u0010i\u0011i\u0012i\u0014i\u0015i\u0016'`

The value that I'm expecting after inflating is something like: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17]`

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem or find a work around?

Comment: Have you tryed `zlib.inflateRaw` instead? @wurde

Comment: Can you show in an answer?

Comment: @Ian where you able to figure out the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Important detail not mentioned above: dalli by default uses ruby native marshalling to serialize the values.

If you want to use the memcached values from multiple languages, consider using a different `serializer`, see the documentation on Configuration https://github.com/petergoldstein/dalli#configuration

Answer (score 0):

Note that Dalli will only compress values over 1K by default, so if your data is less than 1K you're deflating plain text => garbage.

Next, I'm assuming you're reading the right key and not some image or something stored in memcached, so next thing is to try without compression. If it works then there's a difference between the Zlib implementation in the zlib gem and your JS module, so you can try another module.

Note that the output from memcached may need work. For example, I do:

```
    d = Rails.cache.fetch("xdtest", {:expires_in => 60.seconds}) do
        "OKGOFORCACHE"
    end
```

and with:

```
var Memcached = require('memcached');
var memcached = new Memcached('localhost:11211', {retries:10,retry:10000,remove:true,failOverServers:[ ]});


memcached.get('Frontend:xdtest', function (err, data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I get

```
"OKGOFORCACHE:ET
```

Not sure yet if it's a protocol thing or what, so just .log your output after reading the key.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `inflateRaw` like this:

```
client = new Memcached.Client(MEMCACHED_HOSTNAME, Memcached.Adapter.raw);

client.get(key, function (err, response) {
  var data = response[key];

  zlib.inflateRaw(data.buffer, function (err, buf) {
    console.log(err, buf);
  });
});
```